# Access denied error 809 when making a request to coinGecko API

Tags: api, access-denied

I am developing an application on ruby on rails and I am using CoinGeckoAPI to retreive prices of cryptocurrencies. When I make a request I get 809 error Access denied | api.coingecko.com used Cloudflare to restrict access. I do not know how to fix that. I am using windows 10

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnUkB.png)

Comment: I have a quite similar issue, but on Python. Can you add your code and the errors? https://stackoverflow.com/q/68083931/4943299